# How to calculate ΔSST change in time series climate dataset

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, dataset

I have monthly SST and now I am wondering to figure out **ΔSST** in python.
Basically I am unable to understand the **Δ** term meaning as shown in below equation:

[image]

I am calculating the first part of the equation (i.e., partial change) using statsmodel OLS regression slope, but stuck to multiply that slope value with **ΔSST**.

Comment: Probably the difference between the current SST(k) and the previous SST(k-1)?

Comment: @Corralien  exactly what I am understanding from that del symbol. but as I have single slope for a 20 years time series, need to be multiplied by a single value of change. Meaning ΔSST should be a single value for a monthly series of 20years.

Comment: What do you mean? ΔSST is still a vector that you multiply by a scalar value. The output will be a vector.

Comment: @Corralien I am expecting a single value not a series, e.g. 0.3 * ΔSST = 0.6 for a slope value of 0.3 and ΔSST of 2K.

Comment: Do you have a link of your paper and the equation please?

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1002/2015GL065627

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254265/discussion-between-harshbardhan-kumar-and-corralien).